# sql query - get all records based on flag

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table in MS SQL 2008 which has a column called `Status`. It can have "A" or "I" or "P" as values. I have a stored procedure which takes `@Status` as a parameter. If the parameter is `null`, I need to retrieve all the records where the status is either A or I or P (basically ignoring the Status field). If the paramenter is only A (for example), I need to get only records which have A as the status. How do I get this done in a single SELECT statement without `IF.. ELSE`?

```
 -- This is just a snippet of a larger query. 
 -- Can the following be done without IF ELSE?
    IF @Status = NULL
       BEGIN
         SELECT * FROM Person
       END
    ELSE SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = @Status
```

Edit: My goal is not to duplicate the same logic twice. The select statement has a bunch of joins and stuff, and I don't want to repeat it again in the else condition.

Edit #2: My bad - I checked the table again and it does contain records with `NULL` status, which I don't want. Here's the table -

```
Id      Status
--------------
1        A
2        I
3        P
4        NULL
```

If `@Status` is "-1" (I'll default the parameter to -1), I want `1, 2, 3` records. How do I write the query?

Comment: Is there any chance you'll later change your mind and support multiple @Status values? For example show me all rows where Status is A or I but not P?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Nope. It will either have a value or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using OR:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = @Status OR @Status IS NULL
```

Or UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = @Status
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE @Status IS NULL
```

Comment: While this will come off as subjective, I don't find the `UNION ALL` version very attractive at all. If the query is substantially more complex, this can become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

A third option:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Person WHERE Status = COALESCE(@Status, Status);
```

Or you might prefer ISNULL:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Person WHERE Status = ISNULL(@Status, Status);
```

And just for completeness, while the selectivity here is highly unlikely to justify it, you may find that the plans for @Status IS NULL and @Status IS NOT NULL vary widely enough that caching a plan with one or the other can lead to poor performance in the opposite case. One way to deal with this is dynamic SQL. So again, with the disclaimer that this is likely a good option in your case, it is a commonly used alternative to these plan-pinning COALESCE/ISNULL/OR options.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Person' + 
  COALESCE(N' WHERE Status = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Status) + '''', '');

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

And of course you know you [shouldn't be using SELECT * in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), right?

Comment: `And of course you know you shouldn't be using SELECT * in production code, right?` I totally understand. This was just a sample.

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear to other readers, that I was using SELECT * based on your sample, not because I think it's a good idea. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE @Status IS NULL OR Status = @Status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @status CHAR(1)
set @status = 'A'
select * from Person where (@status IS null) or (@status = status)
```

When @status = NULL, this query returns all records.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select * from Person
where (@Status is not null and Status = @Status) or
      (@Status is null and Status in ('A', 'I', 'P'))
```