# sql query - get all records based on a flag

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Apologies for creating a new thread. I was not able to frame the question correctly in the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322099/sql-query-get-all-records-based-on-flag) thread.

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 that looks like this -

```
Id      Status
--------------
1        A
2        I
3        NULL
```

I have a stored procedure which takes `@Status` as the parameter.

```
If the @Status is "-1", I need to retrieve records 1, 2. 
If the @Status is "A", I need to retrieve only record 1.
If the @Status is "I", I need to retrieve only record 2.
```

I want to be able to retrieve the records in a single `SELECT` statement without using `IF ELSE`. There are a lot of joins and stuff in the SELECT statement and I don't want to repeat the same thing in the ELSE condition.

I have tried the following but get incorrect data -

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = @Status OR @Status IS NOT NULL

select * from Person
where (@Status is not null and Status = @Status) or
      (@Status is null and Status in ('A', 'P'))
```

Comment: Why dont you want to use `IF`?

Comment: @Oded: I have tried this - `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = @Status OR @Status IS NULL` but it returns incorrect data. Also, this `select * from Person
where (@Status is not null and Status = @Status) or
      (@Status is null and Status in ('A', 'I', 'P'))` with same results.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: There are a lot of joins and stuff in the `SELECT` statement and I don't want to repeat the same thing in the `ELSE` condition.

Comment: That's something you should include in the question, as well as why they are not working for you.

Comment: @Oded: I'll keep that in mind next time. Sorry about that.

Comment: @enigma: Why do you have to wait until next time? It's allowed to edit your question to make it better. It's even encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE Status = @Status
OR (@Status = '-1' AND Status IS NOT NULL)
```

Of course you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in production code.

Comment: @JohnDewey: But then it would return row 3 if Status is -1, which the OP doesn't seem to want.

Comment: @MarkByers: I could be missing something but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using this - `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = '-1'
OR (@Status = '-1' AND Status IS NOT NULL)`. I'm expecting all the records but I got nothing back.

Comment: @MarkByers: Oops, sorry. I got confused with the parameter and the column name. Works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkByers: So I incorporated this into the original query, and the query has been running for a good five minutes now. I manually stopped it. Are there any performance issues in using this query? The table has 13.2 million records if that matters.

Comment: @Enigma: Yes, there are performance issues. This is why I posted an alternative using UNION ALL on the other thread. If you want help with performance please post the full query, full table definitions, the full execution plan and also state what indexes you have on all tables.

Comment: And when I say full query, I really mean *full*. Do not post a "simplified" version of your actual query because that can change the performance characteristics. If you need to simplify it for some reason, make sure that your simplified query still demonstrates the problem you have.

Comment: @MarkByers: Anyway we can take this offline? Or is it okay if I move this to chat?

Comment: @enigma: I'd rather not, sorry. Besides, you'd benefit more if there are more people who can see your question and vote on the answers. If you "take it offline" you lose the benefits of SO.